# invisible recaptcha wont find callback function in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, recaptcha

All,

The code below represents my register page.  My invisible captcha works as expected but my call back never gets invoked.  I'm using AngularJS..... and the console message I get after the invisible captcha is...ReCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function: register

Is there something wrong with my AngularJS syntax?

In my index.html

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer>
</script>
```

In my register.html

```
<div id='recaptcha' class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey={{key}} data-
callback="register" data-size="invisible"></div>
```

In my controller for register.html

```
$scope.register = function(token) {
  console.log("Data call back worked!" + " Value of token: " + token);
}
```

Comment: Thank you War10ck!  The duplicate solved my issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following: `$window.login = $scope.login;`to register it as a global function. Stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962577/invisible-google-recaptcha-with-angularjs)